# Regular Crashing in Excel - Possible cause referencing entire column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been using Excel from Office 365 for the last 2 years on Windows 10 and get crashes almost daily. I need to have several workbooks open at any one time but don't see why this should be an issue as it wasn't when I was previously using an older version of Excel.
I've just come across a link on the official MS Office website [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-not-responding-hangs-freezes-or-stops-working-37e7d3c9-9e84-40bf-a805-4ca6853a1ff4) and was shocked to see the following;

> The following things can cause performance or crashing issues:
>
> Formulas referencing entire columns.

I'm referencing entire columns all the time using several functions such as  `sumifs`, `average`, etc. eg: `=average(A:A)` and surely I can't be the only one. 
Is this likely to be the cause and does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to reference data in a column is to specify the first and last cell, like `=average(A2:A99)`.
That has some disadvantages, like adding at the bottom is not automatically included in the range, but that's just a matter of getting used to insert before the last line instead.

Using A:A instead is a short-cut that kind-of-works, but if you use the full version, you can avoid your issues.